# Ubuntu upgrade with XFCE makes mouse battery die very fast

Tags: mouse, xfce, battery

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu. I have always disliked Unity because it's so slow so I decided to move to XFCE.

**The problem is**, ever since I did this (1 month ago), I've gone through 3 Energizer batteries and one Duracel battery for my wireless mouse. Usually, a batter will last me 1 month, at least, so this is highly unusual.

I have no idea what to even look for to diagnose this problem. Any guidance would be appreciated. I just put in my 5th battery for the month.

[I'm using the Logitech M210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3swxJ.jpg)

In case any of this helps:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic
```

And:

```
$ aptitude search xfce | grep ^i
i A gtk2-engines-xfce               - GTK+-2.0 theme engine for Xfce            
i   gtk3-engines-xfce               - GTK+-3.0 theme engine for Xfce            
i A libxfce4ui-1-0                  - widget library for Xfce - Gtk+2 variant   
i A libxfce4ui-common               - common files for libxfce4ui               
i A libxfce4ui-utils                - Utility files for libxfce4ui              
i A libxfce4util-bin                - tools for libxfce4util                    
i A libxfce4util-common             - common files for libxfce4util             
i A libxfce4util6                   - Utility functions library for Xfce4       
i A libxfcegui4-4                   - Basic GUI C functions for Xfce4           
i   xfce4                           - Meta-package for the Xfce Lightweight Desk
i A xfce4-appfinder                 - Application finder for the Xfce4 Desktop E
i A xfce4-artwork                   - additional artwork for the Xfce4 Desktop E
i A xfce4-battery-plugin            - battery monitor plugin for the Xfce4 panel
i A xfce4-clipman                   - clipboard history utility                 
i A xfce4-clipman-plugin            - clipboard history plugin for Xfce panel   
i A xfce4-cpufreq-plugin            - cpufreq information plugin for the Xfce4 p
i A xfce4-cpugraph-plugin           - CPU load graph plugin for the Xfce4 panel 
i A xfce4-datetime-plugin           - date and time plugin for the Xfce4 panel  
i A xfce4-dict                      - Dictionary plugin for Xfce4 panel         
i A xfce4-diskperf-plugin           - disk performance display plugin for the Xf
i A xfce4-fsguard-plugin            - filesystem monitor plugin for the Xfce4 pa
i A xfce4-genmon-plugin             - Generic Monitor for the Xfce4 panel       
i   xfce4-goodies                   - enhancements for the Xfce4 Desktop Environ
i A xfce4-mailwatch-plugin          - mail watcher plugin for the Xfce4 panel   
i   xfce4-messenger-plugin          - Dbus messages plugin for xfce4-panel      
i A xfce4-mixer                     - Xfce mixer application                    
i A xfce4-mount-plugin              - mount plugin for the Xfce4 panel          
i A xfce4-netload-plugin            - network load monitor plugin for the Xfce4 
i A xfce4-notes                     - Notes application for the Xfce4 desktop   
i A xfce4-notes-plugin              - Notes plugin for the Xfce4 desktop        
i A xfce4-notifyd                   - simple, visually-appealing notification da
i A xfce4-panel                     - panel for Xfce4 desktop environment       
i A xfce4-places-plugin             - quick access to folders, documents and rem
i   xfce4-power-manager             - power manager for Xfce desktop            
i A xfce4-power-manager-data        - power manager for Xfce desktop, arch-indep
i   xfce4-power-manager-plugins     - power manager plugins for Xfce panel      
i A xfce4-quicklauncher-plugin      - rapid launcher plugin for the Xfce4 panel 
i   xfce4-radio-plugin              - v4l radio control plugin for the Xfce4 pan
i A xfce4-screenshooter             - screenshots utility for Xfce              
i A xfce4-sensors-plugin            - hardware sensors plugin for the Xfce4 pane
i A xfce4-session                   - Xfce4 Session Manager                     
i A xfce4-settings                  - graphical application for managing Xfce se
i A xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin      - search the web via the Xfce4 panel        
i A xfce4-systemload-plugin         - system load monitor plugin for the Xfce4 p
i A xfce4-taskmanager               - process manager for the Xfce4 Desktop Envi
i A xfce4-terminal                  - Xfce terminal emulator                    
i A xfce4-timer-plugin              - timer plugin for Xfce panel               
i A xfce4-verve-plugin              - Verve (command line) plugin for Xfce panel
i A xfce4-volumed                   - volume keys daemon                        
i A xfce4-wavelan-plugin            - wavelan status plugin for the Xfce4 panel 
i A xfce4-weather-plugin            - weather information plugin for the Xfce4 p
i   xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin        - Alternate menu plugin for the Xfce desktop
i A xfce4-xkb-plugin                - xkb layout switch plugin for the Xfce4 pan
```

Comment: Ubuntu can't cause your wireless mouse to use more power. It's just an operating system, and it can't change how quickly your mouse's own battery dies. It will lose power just as quickly regardless of what operating system you use.

Comment: Well, it was working fine until I upgraded and changed to XFCE. Immediately after that, the mouse has been draining the battery. Is there no way a program installed by XFCE can send signals back to my mouse leading it to believing it's reading some sort of movement constantly and therefore causing the battery to die?

Comment: But that is just it. When you use a mouse with a computer, the computer doesn't send any signals like that back to the mouse. There is no way that any combination of software on your computer could cause your mouse to stay on. However, maybe I'm wrong. My suggestion is to use a live CD or live USB of any operating system with Unity or GNOME and then test your mouse batteries. If they last longer when using this Unity/GNOME live CD, I honestly don't know what to tell you except for switch back to Unity (or switch to MATE, which is kind of like Xfce).